# JRuby / Rack deployment

Tags: ruby, deployment, web-applications, jvm, rack

I know this is pretty exotic, but I want to deploy a Ruby web application (not Rails, but Rack based, so it plugs into most Ruby servers just fine) using JRuby. Google and friends give me a few success stories, but mostly rails related and if not, no details on the deployment are provided. The framework I'm using is Ramaze, if it matters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, running a Rack based application with a rackup script is the real Ruby way. And I wanted to apply the same for JRuby too. That is why I've written jetty-rackup http://github.com/geekq/jetty-rackup

We are using it for deploying a Sinatra web application. No Java specific configuration needed. A typical, small config.ru is enough. Embedded jetty web server is used in place of Webrick then.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "just works" gem for me: https://github.com/matadon/mizuno